# Run Shell Commands in iPython in Windows

Tags: shell, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am following the example code from the book "Python Data Science Handbook", and it asked me to type ! to type the shell commands in iPython, however as I was trying to follow along in my Windows laptop this just didn't work. Here's the example code.[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsAie.png)
I have also tried to enter the shell command without having the "!" in the front, but even though it can print the current working directory, I cannot assign the directory to the left hand variable. Could someone tell me how to use this in Windows?

Comment: Are you typing this code in a Jupyter's notebook or are you typing it directly in a windows terminal?

Comment: @ alainlompo I was trying to type in the anaconda prompt, which is like a terminal but might not be as same as the windows default terminal